# Run command on all remotes and get results on local machine with powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I want to run one command remotely on all remotes server(roughly 100 servers).This command collecting all iis and saving in a txt file.

```
(C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list app >C:\Temp\list.txt)
```

Naturally my problem is how to get one list of all remotes in my local machine.I dont want to collect each list on remotes servers.

```
$Servers = @("remotemachine1", "remotemachine2", "remotemachine3" )


foreach ($server in $Servers) {

    $PSSession=New-PsSession -ComputerName $server

    Invoke-command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {

        Write-Verbose -Message "Server: $env:ComputerName" -Verbose


        C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list app >C:\Temp\list.txt

    }
}
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an array to hold the results
2. Instead of output it `C:\Temp\list.txt` use, `Write-Output` and Save it to a Variable
3. Just a tip, Create a custom Object with Column for ServerName so you can identify it in the results.
4. Add each result to the Array
5. Also you don't need to create a new session each time, just use the `-ComputerName` Parameter

So:

```
$Array = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$Servers = @("remotemachine1", "remotemachine2", "remotemachine3" )

foreach ($server in $Servers) {

$Results = Invoke-command -ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    Write-Verbose -Message "Server: $env:ComputerName" -Verbose
    Write-Output (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list app)
}

$Row = "" | Select Server,Results
$Row.Server = $Server
$Row.Results = $Results
[void]$Array.Add($Row)

}
```

Finally the `$Array` should hold it all.

Comment: perfect explain, ty :)

Answer (score 0):

You could return the Content of this file like this:

```
$Servers = @("remotemachine1", "remotemachine2", "remotemachine3" )


foreach ($server in $Servers) {

    $PSSession=New-PsSession -ComputerName $server

    $result = Invoke-command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {

        Write-Verbose -Message "Server: $env:ComputerName" -Verbose


        return (C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list app)
    }

    $result > C:\Temp\list.txt
}
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

Comment: Maybe you also Need a "cat" after the return

Answer (score 0):

You could also pipe the invoke command into a file

`invoke-command -session $pssession -scriptblock { commands on remote machine } | out-file -literalpath "c:\temp\$server-results.txt"`